# Converting Long String to Int in Kotlin

Tags: firebase, kotlin, casting, google-cloud-firestore

Firestore persists values as doubles. No problem, I stored an Int into the Firestore and then I try to read it back as an Int like so:

```
docSnap["myNumber"] as Int
```

When I do I get the exception

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

So that I have to do

```
(docSnap["myNumber"] as Long).toInt()
```

I have two questions:

1. Since when I log `docSnap["myNumber"]` it clearly prints an int, how does the compiler know it was supposed to be a long?
2. Is there a simpler way to convert the "long-String" to an int?

Comment: How do you see the difference between `int` and `long` when you do `docSnap["myNumber"]`? Both `someInt.toString()` and `someLong.toString()` gives the same string as long as `someLong` is within the bounds of an int.

Comment: thanks for replying but I am not able to apply your comments toward a better understanding of the problem: why am I getting an exception for converting the string "9" to Int? Why is it expecting Long?

Comment: I was asking a question about your first question though. You're saying that `docSnap["myNumber"]` is clearly printing an int. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Also, `as Int` does not convert a string to an int. `toInt()` does that.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler doesn't know that it was supposed to be a long.  The types of values in the docSnap Map are just typed as Objects.  You are obliged to either anticipate what the type of a field will be, or check it at runtime.

For Java/JVM languages:

- Floating point field values are *always* going to come back to the SDK as Double type object.
- Integer type fields values are *always* going to comes back to the SDK as a Long type object.

You will need to deal with these as they are, and cast/convert them if they aren't what you want.

Comment: Thanks for replying, but I still don't understand why I got an exception for `docSnap["myNumber"] as Int` when the "number" in question is "9"

Comment: It's just like the error message says. You can't cast the long value to an int. Long doesn't subclass int. It is it's own type, and you have to deal with it as such. These are objects, nob primitive values.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with values that are usually floating points, but could also be a whole number, in a project recently (for our zero-to-app talk at I/O), and ended up with:

```
val amount = documents.data["item_cost"]
if (amount != null && amount is Number) {
    return String.format("%10.2f", amount.toDouble())
}
```

So the key here is to first ensure the value is a `Number`, so that you call `toDouble()` on it.